# node get file description from extension

Tags: node.js, npm

I am reading a list of files in a directory on a linux based system, and want to present to the user of the website both the file name and a description of what that file is.  For example if the extension is .ppt I'd like to give the description "Microsoft PowerPoint" or similar.  I can't imagine I'm the first to ask this question, and found lots of answers for other programming environments using google searches, but nothing specific to node.js.

Note: I am NOT just looking for the mime-type!  I see lots of ways to get the mime-type from an extension.  I'd like the human-readable description of the type, based on the extension of the file.

My gut tells me someone has done this in node and I am just being unsuccessful in finding it with google.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative for you is to just keep your own dictionary of extensions and descriptions as a Javascript object, like this:

```
const Descriptions = {
    'ppt': 'Microsoft Power Point',
    'doc': 'Microsoft Word',
    'pdf': 'Portable Document Format',
    'txt': 'Text Document',
};
```

You can then populate your dictionary with the most famous extension types, here is a nice list: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001789.htm.

To get a particular description, just access the object by property name:

```
const t = Descriptions['ppt'];
console.log(t);
```

This prints:

```
"Microsoft Power Point"
```

Comment: Yes, doing it myself is an option, though I see that as a last resort.  That's why I asked the question if anyone else has already gone through the work to do this.  Perhaps even an on-line database that could be accessed through an API ...

Comment: I believe that simplicity is your friend here and you will be safer by controlling your own dictionary. An online database, as you mentioned, may be offline when you need it the most. That's just my two cents. I hope you find a nice solution.

Comment: I ended up following your advice and building my own.  I took raw data from here: https://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/fileextensionsfull.asp and transformed it into something more easily read by javascript, placed it in a flat file and spawned a 'grep' process to search for the extension and return the resulting line, making it easy to parse for the description.  Since the heart of your answer was "keep your own dictionary of extensions and descriptions", I'm going to accept your answer as the solution.